# Confirm("Message") does not appear when putting in <?php ?>

Tags: php, anchor, href, confirmation

The `onclick='return confirm('Delete this comment?')'` seems to be not working at all:

```
<?php           
     if($sesType == 'Admin') {
        echo "<a href = 'editCom.php?id=$commentID'>Edit</a> ";
        echo "<a href='deleteCom.php?id=$commentID' onclick='return confirm('Delete this comment?')'>Delete</a>";
    } else if($_SESSION["username"] != NULL AND $_SESSION["username"] == $postname) {
        echo "<a href = 'editCom.php?id=$commentID'>Edit</a>  ";
        echo "<a href='deleteCom.php?id=$commentID' onclick='return confirm('Delete this comment?')'>Delete</a>";
    }
?>
```

But the confirmation box does not appear.

Comment: I also tried to do in javascript but same result

Comment: You are mixing quote chars in a way that won't work.

Comment: Take a look into the browsers javascript console, you will probably see an error message when you click the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using single quotes inside of single quotes. Use double quotes to wrap your code instead:

```html
<a href='#' onclick="return confirm('Confirmation Message')">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code, and it will work.

```
echo "<a href='deleteCom.php?id=$commentID' onclick="return confirm('Delete this comment?')">Delete</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misused the single quote and double quotes. You have to put slash ()  on quotes to escape. The html should look like this:

```
 <a href='#' onclick="return confirm('Confirmation Message')">Link</a>
```

Take note that single quote should be inserted inside the double quotes ""

from your code:

```
echo " <a href='deleteCom.php?id=$commentID' onclick='return confirm('Delete this comment?')'>Delete</a>";
```

**It should be:**

```
 echo "<a href=\"deleteCom.php?id={$commentID}\" onclick=\"return confirm('Delete this comment?')\">Delete</a>";
```